# Restore Delphi environmental paths

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

In Delphi 10 Seattle, I clicked the "Delete invalid paths" button in `Options->Library->LibraryPath` and it messed with some of the default environmental paths.  Is there a way to restore the default settings?

For example:

`$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\`
`$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp\$(Platform)`

(these are invalid)

Comment: It is a shame that the delete button is *still* not smart enough to ignore paths that contain variables populated at compile-time, like `$(Platform)` , instead of treating them as invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are default and build in way for restore your settings. This way available for many years (more than 15)

run Delphi with command line parameters -rXXX

`bds.exe -rXXX`. What will happen:

> The name you provide after -r is a registry hive. If that registry
>   hive does not exist, the IDE create a brand new registry hive with all
>   the defaults and uses it. Because this takes you back to all the
>   default settings, it fixes most start up problems with the IDE. Note
>   that because custom controls are not part of the defaults, this
>   technique will result in your IDE not having any custom controls you
>   have installed previously. Custom controls are the most common cause
>   of this error, so you will probably want to add any you have one at a
>   time and test.
>
> Your new registry hive will be stored in the registry at
>   HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\name\version. Your current settings for the
>   IDE are stored at HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\version. You can
>   compare the two registry hives using regedit to see what is different.

you could restore your Library/Browsing path from new environment, by copy them from XXX environment and paste it to regular one.

Read more at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options and on http://support.embarcadero.com/es/article/42597

Comment: thanks for your response.  This is an interesting approach and being new to delphi I always appreciate any reference to embarcodero.

Comment: This is a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to restore them short of a reinstall. However, here are the ones I have in my Seattle installation (which should be pretty vanilla, since it's a fairly fresh install on a new laptop and I've been using Berlin). I'll put it in two formats - a direct copy/paste version and a list of individual items, so you can use either easily.

Single line copy/paste:

```
$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release;$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp\$(Platform);$(BDS)\include;
```

Individual entries:

```
$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release;
$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports;
$(BDS)\Imports;
$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp\$(Platform);
$(BDS)\include;
```

Comment: I tried a modify/repair install right before i saw this but it still didn't do the trick. It did seem to restore these paths except for : $(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release;  Still testing it out to see what is missing.

Comment: Modify/repair won't do it, AFAIK. You need to do an uninstall, check the box to remove registry entries, and then reinstall from scratch. (Or you can just copy/paste the first code block I posted and skip all of that work.)

Comment: There are default and build in way for restore your settings. This way available for many years (more than 15). your 'solution' is bad practice.

Comment: your answer do not explain how really restore library path for any (most) version of Delphi.